# Fuzzy Clip Layer to maintain feature geometry

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.3, clip

I have a number of large datasets that I want to clip to a specific area to make more manageable and carry out further processing. I have a polygon outline of my AOI, however I don't want to hard cut the features to this, rather select and then export all the features that 'intersect' it, therefore retaining the original datas geomtetry and attributes - in the same way that a select by location does.

(I realise that I could individually export the selected features but I'm hoping there is a tool or process that will allow me to batch multiple layers to export at the same time as I need to repeat this process for multiple locations)

So my question:

**How can I 'fuzzy' clip data rather than 'hard' clipping it?**

In the example below I want to export the features that intersect the blue polygon (my AOI) including the features highlighted by the red boxes that cross the boundary of the AOI, but without cutting or editing their geometry.

[image: Example of 'fuzzy clip']

Answer (score 2):

This will work on non-overlapping AOIs. Create point layer from your polylines (midpoint), labelpoint (polygon). Join points spatially to AOIs.
Transfer AOI ids back to parent tables. Batch export.

Comment: That approach assumes that any intersecting features have their midpoint in the AOI. In the example above the line shown in the bottom red box would not be included using this technique - it might be possible to use a similar approach with the start / end points of the line though